# What does "Ho Ho" mean in English?

Tags: translation, anime

I hear this frequently when I watch anime. Google digging suggests it means cheek 頬. But this does not make contextual sense to me for the times I've heard it used.

For example, at 14:45 in episode 2 of Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood. The subtitles indicate nothing about a cheek.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, "ho ho" is a kind of quaint laughter used to express joy.

....

You've mistaken ほほ (hoho) with ほうほう (houhou).

> [[方法]{ほうほう}](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)
>   Noun
>   1. method; process; manner; way; means; technique​
>   (Jisho)

The character was talking about some kind of method involving bodies.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much! That was quite helpful.